# List of defined super methods for a certain class method in ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance, reflection, mixins, super

I am working on a system with a some complex class/mixin hierarchy. As there are several numerous layers scattered over many different files, I want to quickly see what the chain of super calls is for a given method.

For example

```
module AAA
  def to_s
    "AAA " + super()
  end
end

module BBB
  def to_s
    "BBB " + super()
  end
end

class MyArray < Array
  include AAA
  include BBB

  def to_s
    "MyArray " + super()
  end
end

> MyArray.new.to_s
=> "MyArray BBB AAA []"
> method_supers(MyArray,:to_s)
=> ["MyArray#to_s", "BBB#to_s", "AAA#to_s", "Array#to_s", ...]
```

Comment: If someone thinks of a better title, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
class A
  def foo; p :A; end
end

module B
  def foo; p :B; super; end
end

module C; end

class D < A
  include B, C
  def foo; p :D; super; end
end

p D.ancestors.keep_if { |c| c.instance_methods.include? :foo }  # [D, B, A]
```

If that seems right, you could amend this function accordingly:

```
def Object.super_methods(method)
  ancestors.keep_if { |c| c.instance_methods.include? method }
end

p D.super_methods(:foo)  # [D, B, A]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def method_supers(child_class,method_name)
  ancestry = child_class.ancestors

  methods = ancestry.map do |ancestor|
    begin
      ancestor.instance_method(method_name)
    rescue
      nil
    end
  end

  methods.reject!(&:nil?)

  methods.map {|m| m.owner.name + "#" + m.name.to_s}
end
```

Comment: Your code can be improved, so why you didn't put it in the question itself,asking people here for other choices or improvement to your code.

Comment: Because it is an answer. Nothing prevents people from posting another one or commenting to suggest improvements. Why don't you suggest an improvement?

Comment: @OMG I think it would actually be really cool if there was a website where you could submit your code and have people in the field review it and help you improve by commenting on it and telling you how they would approach the problem differently, optimize it or even just a more standardized approach for that particular language because when I first started learning ruby I was trying to right a for loop instead of a .each loop.

Comment: @ratelle I agree it is an answer and a starting point to help someone else, it doesn't have to be the best thing you have ever written